# BASH date command: can't re-combine date and time

Tags: linux, bash, date

Linux v2.4/Bash v3.2/GNU utils/date command version 5.0

I'm struggling with the date command. In a BASH application, the user can set date and time separately, resulting in separate variables for date and time. Further on, these variables are re-combined but this appears not be palatable for the date command: I get a different date back. Time is the same, however. Testing code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dnow1="$(date)"
echo "1 $dnow1"                             # --> Sat Sep 14 16:31:48 EDT 2013
#split date and time
dldate="$(date -d "$dnow1" +"%d-%m-%Y")"
echo "2 $dldate"                            # --> 14-09-2013
dltime="$(date -d "$dnow1" +"%H:%M:%S")"
echo "3 $dltime"                            # --> 16:31:48
#try to re-combine date and time
string="${dldate} ${dltime}"
echo "4 $string"                            # --> 14-09-2013 16:31:48
dnow2="$(date -d "$string")"
echo "5 $dnow2"                             # --> Thu Mar 5 16:31:48 EST 2020
```

I must be missing something here. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!

Note:
I'm working an original XBOX that has few/low resources so there's no room for other solutions like Python. I'm a 'bashist' anyway so it must be BASH!

Edit: corrected time format. Thanks Mat. 
As to "$(....)" I have made it a habit to double quote wherever possible.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? `set -- $(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` will give you the date part in `$1` and the time in `$2`.

Comment: %d-%m-%Y and %H:%M:%S are in variables, dldate and dltime respectively. date -d "${dldate} {dltime}" gives a wrong year. However swapping %Y and %d does the trick in this case, as suggested by member konsolebox. Maybe I should have mentioned that this is about virtual dates, not hw or sw dates.

Comment: But why do you need them in variables, or rather, why do you require a roundtrip back to `date`? If you can tell us your actual end goal, we can probably propose a solution which avoids the roundtrip, or solves it more elegantly.

Comment: A bunch of files have a random names, preceded by K-keep R-remove D-done or ssssssssss- for epoch seconds for download time/date. In a text menu the download time/date are set in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS as separate inputs, like "set date:" and the next line "set time:". The date/time input is converted into epoch seconds and thus the prefix of the file involved. To show the download date/time in in the menu, epoch seconds are converted back to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Furthermore, the date/time input is scrollable with arrow keys (no typing). I hope it explains why I'm using variables for date/time.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem. Adding "SOLVED" to the title or to the question isn't appropriate for [so] since this is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting your date use this format instead:

```
#split date and time
dldate="$(date -d "$dnow1" +"%Y-%m-%d")"
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks a lot! Apparently, the logic here is that the highest value should come first, i.e Y-m-d for date and H:M:S for time?

Answer (score 0):

First of all using `-d` won't work in `14-09-2013` fashion, you can easily set date and time with one command and put it into variable. *eg*, just try this below on shell and then you can put into shell script.

```
date --date="Feb 2 2014 13:12:10"  
Sun Feb  2 13:12:10 PST 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

From [GNU date manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html#SEC120)

> The output of the date command is not always acceptable as a date string, not only because of the language problem, but also because there is no standard meaning for time zone items like ‘IST’. When using date to generate a date string intended to be parsed later, specify a date format that is independent of language and that does not use time zone items other than ‘UTC’ and ‘Z’.